# Making query combining, one to many relationships in JPA with JPQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, repository, jpql

I have a database. with a one to many relationships.

```
pet 1--* event.
```

I want to make a query, that selects all pets, that has had an event on a given date. (I'm using the SQL date format)

As of now I just want to be able to get all entities, for a hardcoded date.

here is the reference in my PetEntity table

```
@OneToMany
private List<EventEntity> events = new ArrayList();
```

and in my EventEntity

```
@ManyToOne
PetEntity pet;
```

I'm using a pattern where I use a repository to handle the data layer, and then a facade to handle any logic(if any)

So far I have made a method like this.

```
  public Set<PetEntity> getPetsWithEvents(Date date){
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Set<PetEntity> entities = new HashSet<>();
    List<EventEntity> eventEntities=  
em.createQuery("SELECT e from EventEntity e where e.date =: date", EventEntity.class).setParameter("date", date).getResultList();
        for(EventEntity entity: eventEntities){
            entities.add(entity.getPet());
        }
        return  entities;
   }
}
```

Is there a way to simply method this method into using one query, instead of looping through the vent and finding each pet?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join

Comment: So i could use a join to select the pets, where the vent is a certain value?

Comment: Replace Pet by Person, Event by Phone, and Event.date by Phone.type, and the query you want is exactly the one shown as the first example of the section I linked to.

Comment: By phone do you mean date?

Comment: just select from pet join with event

Comment: Thank you. Feel free to post as answer aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others already mentioned, you should be able to select pet join event.
The JPQL will be something like below:

```
SELECT p FROM PetEntity p join p.events e
WHERE e.date =: date
```